# Create pandas column with a condition based on a range of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column that if a range of 5 columns all have the same value, it will have that value. Otherwise, it will have "Error".

From this:

```
|1 1 1 1 1|
|2 2 2 2 2|
|0 1 2 2 1|
|z z z z z|
```

To this:

```
|1 1 1 1 1| 1
|2 2 2 2 2| 2
|0 1 2 2 1| Error
|z z z z z| z
```

Is there a way to do this without iterating over each row?

Comment: `df.all(axis=1)` gives you a series of True/False according as each row has one single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use #[`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with test same values by [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df.nunique(axis=1).eq(1), df.iloc[:, 0], 'error')
```

Or for better performance test first column if same values like all columns:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1), df.iloc[:, 0], 'error')
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4    new
0  1  1  1  1  1      1
1  2  2  2  2  2      2
2  0  1  2  2  1  error
3  z  z  z  z  z      z
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! The second line didn't work for me for some reason, but the first one did except for empty strings, but I can do a workaround for that.

Comment: @blueseal - Maybe because `NaN`s, then for secon dis possible use `df1 = df.fillna('empty')` `df['new'] = np.where(df1.eq(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1), df1.iloc[:, 0], 'error')`